# EF Core 2.1.4 Include is performing INNER JOIN on Optional Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some trouble including an entity related entity with the `Include` method in the query.

```
var array = this.DbContext.Set<CustomerBranchOffice>()
.Where(x => 1 == 1) //JUST FOR THE EXAMPLE
.Include(x => x.CustomerWebSiteBrand)
.ToArray();
```

The related entity `CustomerWebSiteBrand` in `CustomerBranchOffice` could be null if there is no match in the `CustomerSiteBrand` table. But the `Include` method is always performing an `INNER JOIN` and not the desired `LEFT JOIN`. This is filtering me all the `CustomerBranchOffice`´s rows that does not match the `INNER JOIN`.

The SQL server tables are the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
    (
        Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        WebSite VARCHAR(100) NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Brands
    (
        BrandCode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerBranchOffices
    (
        Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        IdCustomer INT NOT NULL,
        Location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        BrandCode  VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerBranchOffices_Brands FOREIGN KEY (BrandCode) REFERENCES dbo.Brands(BrandCode),
        CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerBranchOffices_Brands FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES dbo.Customers(Id)
    )

    CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerWebSiteBrands
    (
        Id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
        BrandCode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        BrandWebSiteUrl VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        UNIQUE (CustomerId, BrandCode),
        CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerWebSiteBrands_Brands FOREIGN KEY (BrandCode) REFERENCES dbo.Brands(BrandCode),
        CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerWebSiteBrands_Brands FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES dbo.Customers(Id)
    )
```

The entities and mappings are the following:

```
public class CustomerBranchOffice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string BrandCode { get; set; }

    public CustomerWebSiteBrand CustomerWebSiteBrand { get; set; }
}

public CustomerBranchOfficeMap(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerBranchOffice> entityBuilder)
{
    entityBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.IdCustomer)
        .HasColumnName("IdCustomer")
        .HasColumnType("INTEGER")
        .IsRequired();

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.Location)
        .HasColumnName("Location")
        .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(100)");

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.BrandCode)
            .HasColumnName("BrandCode")
            .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(5)")
            .IsRequired();

    entityBuilder.HasOne(x => x.CustomerWebSiteBrand)
        .WithOne(x => x.CustomerBranchOffices)
        .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.IdCustomer, x.BrandCode } }) // The join is performed using these two properties (NOT NULLABLES)
        .HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.IdCustomer, x.BrandCode });
}

public class CustomerWebSiteBrand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    public string BrandCode { get; set; }

    public string BrandWebSiteUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomerBranchOffice> CustomerBranchOffices { get; set; }
}

public CustomerWebSiteBrandMap(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerWebSiteBrand> entityBuilder)
{
    entityBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.IdCustomer)
        .HasColumnName("IdCustomer")
        .HasColumnType("INTEGER")
        .IsRequired();

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.BrandCode)
            .HasColumnName("BrandCode")
            .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(5)")
            .IsRequired();

    entityBuilder.Property(x => x.BrandWebSiteUrl)
            .HasColumnName("BrandWebSiteUrl")
            .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(100)")
            .IsRequired();

    entityBuilder.HasMany(x => x.CustomerBranchOffices)
        .WithOne(x => x.CustomerWebSiteBran)
        .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.IdCustomer, x.BrandCode } }) // The join is performed using these two properties (NOT NULLABLES)
        .HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.IdCustomer, x.BrandCode });
}
```

As you can see, the relationship is performed using the properties `IdCustomer` and `BranchCode`. Both are required in both entities.

I tried using `new { IdCustomer = (int?)x.IdCustomer, x.BrandCode }` in the `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrincipalKey` config, but stills, the ORM performs a `INNER JOIN`. Is there any way I can force a `LEFT JOIN` using the `Include` method?

Comment: Please always indicate which version you're using. Esp. with EF-core that may make a large difference.

Comment: Added @GertArnold. Thanks

Comment: EF Core supports only physical enforced FK relationships. Hence the "optionality" of the relationship is determined by the nullability of the FK field(s). In your case, the relationships is considered required and there is no way to change that.

Comment: @IvanStoev there must be a workaround to solve this issue. I tried creating two properties mapped to the same column, one property nullable and the original one. But now I have another error: "are both mapped to column but are configured with different nullability."

Comment: I have the same problem in efcore 6. I have a nullable Guid? key, but the Include creates INNER JOIN...